# Class variables vs configuration dicts

Tags: python

Consider these two approaches:

**Configuration dictionary within class**

```
DEFAULT_PARAMETERS = {
    "name": "Generic Room",
    "description": "This is a sample description."
}

class Room:
    """Base class for a room"""

    def __init__(self, parameters=DEFAULT_PARAMETERS):
        for key, value in parameters.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)
        for key, value in DEFAULT_PARAMETERS.items():
            if getattr(self, key, None) is None:
                setattr(self, key, value)
```

**Proper class structure**

```
class Room:
    """Base class for a room"""

    name = "Generic Room"
    description = "This is a sample description."

    def __init__(self, parameters):
        for key, value in parameters.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)
```

I'm not very well-versed in Python, and the languages I come from (PHP, C++) along with my existing experience lead me to believe that the second approach is how things are meant to be done in general.

The core issue lies in the discussion I had with my friend about how to organize different room generation for our game project - I firmly adhere to the second approach, with each type of Room (Kitchen, Hallway, Living Room, Bedroom) being its separate class inherited from room, while he insists that it's entirely unnecessary because of how "small" each room class looks (there's not a lot of functionality right now) and how it's "unnecessary to create so many class files for very similar entities".

I've argumented my point with concepts like encapsulation, separation of concerns and single responsibility principle, but he's very averse to creating more classes, preferring to use those parameter dicts which would be stored in a configuration module. I'm unaware whether this is a valid approach in Python, but that's not how I'd ever design architecture. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: You're asking about whether to use fields or a dictionary but your problem seems to be more around whether to use inheritance or configuration... What's the real question here? FWIW I would avoid inheritance, have a single `Room` class and make the things that differ between types of rooms be injectable configuration or behaviour... how those things are stored internally to the instance really doesn't matter very much. Your two examples are only really trivially different.

Comment: @AntP Basically that would be what this boils down to, inheritance vs. configuration. Thanks for the input! Why would you prefer that?

Comment: [Composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). Having a single room class and injecting appropriate behaviours and rules gives you much more flexibility than having rigidly-defined classes where different features of a particular room type are inherently coupled together. Then you can use factory methods to build appropriate room instances for each room type (`var kitchen = new Room(features)`).

Comment: Inheritance is completely pointless if the only difference between your classes is the data that they store.    The cases where inheritance can be useful are situations where your derived classes are going to provide some additional or different behaviour/functionality by introducing new methods or overriding existing methods.      If you don't have any different behaviour or functionality in your derived classes, then inheritance is not useful and provides no benefits;  all it does is create unnecessary extra code which serves no purpose.

Comment: @BenCottrell As development progresses, I expect classes to contain unique functionality later down the line - I'm faimilar with the main purposes of inheritance. But if it were like this, you suggest retaining composition?

Comment: @IvanT.   That might be a compelling argument in favour of inheritance, but composition is usually easier to manage.    "it depends" -- the downside of inheritance is that the derived classes are very tightly coupled (dependent upon) their base class;  i.e.  it is impossible to separate derived-class behaviour from base-class behaviour because it's all inherited.     That may or may not be a problem;  chances are you will only find out whether it's a problem once you've already written the code, so then you'd probably need to refactor to composition.   Or you can just start with composition.

Answer (score 2):

In your game what are rooms for?

If a room is used to navigate from room to room and access it's contents your kitchen type is completely unnecessary.

If you need to be able to send a `cook_a_meal()` message and have it's resolution depend on your room then EVERY room has to be able to accept that message. Even if the rooms response is to leave the food uncooked.

Expanding what a type can do with inheritance isn't something you do because some things can do it and some things can't. It's something you do because this extra thing you need didn't exist when the system was first designed and now you need kitchen to be both a room and a food preparation service. That's only needed if something somewhere had no idea `cook_a_meal()` existed when it was created and that something isn't going to change.

In other words, inheritance is something you do to pre-existing types that now need to be more than what they once were yet still need to work where they always worked before.

So don't reach for inheritance to solve green field problems. If you know food prep is something a room might be asked to do give every room a way to respond to that. The room can delegate to a food prep object that might be a stove or a table Maybe all you can make there is a bowl of cereal or maybe nothing at all [(see null object pattern)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern).

Composition and delegation give you almost the same power that inheritance does. The difference is that you can't hack composition and delegation into an existing class without changing it unless it already had it. Inheritance lets you step between an existing class and it's clients (those that use it) without changing any of them. That's it's unique power. It's useful.

However, repeatedly using that power on one type leads to a nightmare called [the yo-yo problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yo-yo_problem). If you're in an established code base and need to add inheritance where it didn't exist before then give the child it's own composition and delegation so that the inheritance stack never grows beyond this. Use composition to make sure no one has to inherit again.

Over-zealously avoiding inheritance is what leads to designs where every type has an interface. Inheritance definitely has issues. But it exists for a reason. Save it to retrofit old classes. Just don't make it your designs central way to do polymorphism. When you know ahead of time that you'll need polymorphism reach for composition and delegation. When you find out later and can't change existing classes reach for inheritance and give those of us that come after you the power to avoid doing it again.

Answer (score 2):

As for configuration, if you use a Dictionary, (especially if you place it into a separate file), it is possible for a reasonably competent *non programmer* to edit.  This may be an advantage.

For example, if you are working with a creative type for a game, or a marketing person for your business, and the description of rooms or products changes or expands fairly often, they can do the editing instead of a harried programmer.

You'll like this until they mess things up.  :-)

An improvement would be to use something like JSON, YAML, or a .ini file format which are even more "human readable" and might be easier for them to understand, has access to better editors, etc...